Maximize finds solution outside the constraint
I'm trying to maximize a (quite simple) polynomial inside a sphere. The command is simply:
f[x1_, x2_, x3_] := -(x1/36) + x1^3/67 + x2/25 - (x1^2  x2)/12 + (x1  x2^2)/15 - x2^3/30 + 
   x3/27 - (2  x1^2  x3)/11 + (x1  x2  x3)/35 - (x2^2  x3)/11 + 
   x1^2  x2^2  x3 + (x1  x3^2)/22 - (x2  x3^2)/18 - x3^3/49;
Maximize[{f[x1, x2, x3], x1^2 + x2^2 + x3^2 <= 1}, {x1, x2, x3}] // N

The result I get is:
(* {-149457., {x1 -> -0.873639, x2 -> 64.5, x3 -> -48.}} *)

which grossly violates the constraint x1^2 + x2^2 + x3^2 <= 1, and even the function's value is incoherent, since it has positive values both within the constraint and outside.
To me, this seems like a textbook usage of Maximize. Is this a Mathematica bug?

As @Domen showed, this is not a bug. Maximize returns a result that satisfies the constraint. But numericizing that result is prone to cancelllation error.

If you drop N, you will see that the result is a very long and complex expression, full of high-degree Root objects. I would say that the result isn't really a bug, but shows an accumulation of numerical errors, which you can avoid by using arbitrary-precision calculations (set by the second argument of N), for example,
Maximize[{f[x1, x2, x3], x1^2 + x2^2 + x3^2 <= 1}, {x1, x2, x3}] // N[#, 5]&
(* {0.057092, {x1 -> -0.87364, x2 -> -0.026513, x3 -> -0.48585}} *)

Alternatively, you can use numerical maximization with NMaximize:
NMaximize[{f[x1, x2, x3], x1^2 + x2^2 + x3^2 <= 1}, {x1, x2, x3}]
(* {0.0570927, {x1 -> -0.873678, x2 -> -0.0266629, x3 -> -0.485778}} *)


I would have thought that N[Maximize[...]] and Maximize[...] // N would do the same thing in Mathematica and yield the same results.  Why don't they?

@MichaelSeifert, hmm, have you perhaps missed that there is a second argument: N[Maximize[...], 5], where 5 is the desired precision?

Ah, I did miss that.  So Maximize[... , 5] // N should yield the same result.

@MichaelSeifert, I've edited the answer to emphasize that. But I am not really sure what you mean by Maximize[... , 5] // N ...

That was a mistake on my part, trying to figure out how one would get the same results using the postfix notation.  The command you used in your revised version is what I had in mind but failed to express correctly.
